# How to use a stored url from Firebase Database as an image in an UIImageView

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uiimageview

I'm new to coding and trying to build an iOS App. I am storing images uploaded by users into my firebase storage and then saving the URL as a string ("https//.....). I am able to get a snapshot to show up in project terminal after I use print(snapshot). It prints, snap (profileImageUrl) https://firebasestorage.... How do I use this snapshot to get the ImageView to show the profile picture most recently saved?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import SDWebImage


class EditProfileViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var ProfileImage: UIImageView!

        var selectedImage: UIImage?

        var ref:DatabaseReference?

        var databaseHandle:DatabaseHandle = 0

        var postProfileImage = [String]()

let dbref = Database.database().reference()
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
           self.ref?.child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("profileImageUrl").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                print(snapshot)
           })


            ProfileImage.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
            ProfileImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
            ProfileImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            ProfileImage.layer.cornerRadius = ProfileImage.frame.size.width / 2
            ProfileImage.clipsToBounds = true

            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(EditProfileViewController.handleSelectProfileImageView))
            ProfileImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
            ProfileImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

        @objc func handleSelectProfileImageView() {
        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.delegate = self
        present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    }

@IBAction func Cancel(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

let fileData = NSData()


@IBAction func DoneButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
guard let imageSelected = self.ProfileImage.image else {
    print ("Avatar is nil")
    return
}

    var dict: Dictionary<String, Any> = [
        "profileImageUrl": "",

    ]

guard let imageData = imageSelected.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.4) else {
    return
}
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "(I have my storage url here")
    let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
    let storageProfileRef = storageRef.child("Profile_Images").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("\(imageName).png")

let metadata = StorageMetadata()
metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
storageProfileRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata, completion:
    { (StorageMetadata, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            return
        }

        storageProfileRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
            if let metaImageUrl = url?.absoluteString {
                dict["profileImageUrl"] = metaImageUrl

                Database.database().reference().child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).updateChildValues(dict, withCompletionBlock:  {
                    (error, ref) in
                    if error == nil {
                        print("Done")
                    }
                    }

                )
            }
        }

})


    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

      }

 }
     extension EditProfileViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
       func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
           //print("did Finish Picking Media")
           if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey(rawValue: "UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage")] as? UIImage{
               selectedImage = image
               ProfileImage.image = image
           }
           dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
   }
```

I could really use some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an extension to UIImageView as below:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func load(url: URL, onLoadCompletion: ((_ isImageLoaded: Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.image = nil
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.image = image
                        onLoadCompletion?(true)
                    }
                } else {
                    onLoadCompletion?(false)
                }
            } else {
                onLoadCompletion?(false)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming your image view outlet is something like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
```

Below is the usage when adding a loader:

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://firebase-storage-url") {
    // show a loader here if needed
    imageView.load(url: url) { (imageLoaded) in
        if imageLoaded {
            // hide loader
        } else {
            // show a place holder image
            // hide loader
        }
    }
} else {
    // show a default image
}
```

Below is the usage without any extra work and just loading the image:

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://firebase-storage-url") {
    imageView.load(url: url)
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your help. The UIImage is not loading and I am getting a NSErrorFailingURLStringKey. I don't know if this is relevant but I really need help fast.

Comment: This error comes from the Firebase APIs sometimes. Can you show me the stack trace or let me know which line is getting this issue in your code and what is the complete message?

Comment: I don't know if this is what you want to see. Sorry, I am very new to this.                                  Task <FC0D2B28-FF79-4914-921A-B501D782D62C>.<2> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1003 [12:8])